# How can I update Ubuntu while using a dual boot setup?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, updates

Currently, I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 11 on my laptop, and use the GRUB menu to select which operating system to boot into at startup.

A software package I need to use has updated, and it supports Ubuntu 22.04, so I'd like to try to update Ubuntu. However, I am a noob at Linux, and I remember the mess I had when I tried to downgrade Ubuntu by deleting it and then reinstalling. This worked until I had to restart the computer, and then GRUB didn't recognize my boot options and I was stuck for a little. I eventually solved the problem by booting into Windows and deleting the GRUB partition and starting over.

I'd like to avoid this problem going forward, so before I do anything I'd like to ask if there is a proper way to do this without messing up my dual boot config. I'm aware of the method to update Ubuntu through the command line, found that on Google. However the answer made no mention of dual boot configurations and GRUB.

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: For most dual-boot users, a plain old `do-release-upgrade` will automatically update GRUB, too. However, we don't know what haywiring you have done to GRUB -- if heavily customized or improperly installed, it might indeed fail at your next boot. Also keep in mind that `do-release-upgrade` won't be available for 20.04 users until August 2022, so you might be a bit early.

Comment: You first need good backups of both Windows & Ubuntu. With Ubuntu you really only need to back up all your data typically in /home, list of installed apps and anything in /etc (like grub) that you customized. But do not automatically restore /etc as that may not always be correct for a new install.

Comment: @user535733 AFAIK I haven't messed with my GRUB install, the only thing I've done is use grub-customizer to move Windows up higher on the list. Thanks for the info on do-release-upgrade, I'll be sure to keep an eye out then.